# Помощь с OWL-carusel и выпадающий список

Tags: список, owl-carousel

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".item").hover(
    function() { $('.grid_subcat', this).fadeIn("fast"); 
    },
    function() { $('.grid_subcat', this).fadeOut("fast");               
     });
   
              var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
              owl.owlCarousel({
                margin: 10,
                nav: true,
                loop: false,
                responsive: {
                  0: {
                    items: 1
                  },
                  600: {
                    items: 3
                  },
                  1000: {
                    items: 5
                  }
                }
              })
            });
```

```css
.grid_subcat{
 background:#fff;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding:10px;
 display:none;
 list-style:none; 
 position:absolute!important;
 z-index:1000;
 width:auto;
 min-width:160px;
 height:auto;
 top:50%;
 left:-17px;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/css/docs.theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<section id="demos">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
          <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <div class="item">
              <h4>1</h4>
     <ul class="grid_subcat">
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h4>2</h4>
     <ul class="grid_subcat">
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h4>3</h4>
     <ul class="grid_subcat">
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h4>4</h4>
     <ul class="grid_subcat">
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h4>5</h4>
     <ul class="grid_subcat">
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h4>6</h4>
     <ul class="grid_subcat">
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h4>7</h4>
     <ul class="grid_subcat">
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h4>8</h4>
     <ul class="grid_subcat">
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h4>9</h4>
     <ul class="grid_subcat">
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h4>10</h4>
     <ul class="grid_subcat">
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h4>11</h4>
     <ul class="grid_subcat">
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h4>12</h4>
     <ul class="grid_subcat">
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

[image: как сделать что бы выпадающий список выходил за границы карусели?]

как сделать что бы выпадающий список выходил за границы карусели?
кто может помочь, уже три дня ломаю голову над этим.
Ребят, есть специалисты тут, которые смогут помочь с этой задачей или хотя бы сказать что это не реально?
 [архив с каруселью и списком](https://yadi.sk/d/pFIrJjc53PYePy)

Comment: выложите код на on-line сервис, чтобы людям не пришлось качать ваш проект, а они могли бы посмотреть в браузере и при желании скачать

Comment: это не проект, это просто демо версия скрипта карусели с официального сайта и в нем я добавил выпадающий список..

Comment: если эта демо версия скрипта состоит из кода (вдруг ещё из чего-то), выложите его на он-лайн ресурс, чтобы людям не пришлось ничего скачивать.

Comment: Добавил..это стандартный скрипт карусели..как бороться с этим..проблема в том что в стиле карусели .owl-stage-outer стоит overflow: hidden; из за него список не показывается полностью

Answer (score 0):

Внешний контейнер .owl-stage-outer имеет параметр overflow: hidden, который обрезает выпадающее меню. Можно добавить в css например так:

```
.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer{
    overflow: unset!important;
}
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".item").hover(
    function() { $('.grid_subcat', this).fadeIn("fast"); 
    },
    function() { $('.grid_subcat', this).fadeOut("fast");               
     });
   
              var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
              owl.owlCarousel({
                margin: 10,
                nav: true,
                loop: false,
                responsive: {
                  0: {
                    items: 1
                  },
                  600: {
                    items: 3
                  },
                  1000: {
                    items: 5
                  }
                }
              })
            });
```

```css
.grid_subcat{
 background:#fff;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding:10px;
 display:none;
 list-style:none; 
 position:absolute!important;
 z-index:1000;
 width:auto;
 min-width:160px;
 height:auto;
 top:50%;
 left:-17px;}

.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer{
    overflow: unset!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/css/docs.theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<section id="demos">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
          <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <div class="item">
              <h4>1</h4>
     <ul class="grid_subcat">
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h4>2</h4>
     <ul class="grid_subcat">
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h4>3</h4>
     <ul class="grid_subcat">
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h4>4</h4>
     <ul class="grid_subcat">
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h4>5</h4>
     <ul class="grid_subcat">
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h4>6</h4>
     <ul class="grid_subcat">
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h4>7</h4>
     <ul class="grid_subcat">
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h4>8</h4>
     <ul class="grid_subcat">
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h4>9</h4>
     <ul class="grid_subcat">
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h4>10</h4>
     <ul class="grid_subcat">
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h4>11</h4>
     <ul class="grid_subcat">
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h4>12</h4>
     <ul class="grid_subcat">
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
      <li><a href="{%$uri%}{%$el2.uri%}/">первый</a> </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: тогда вся карусель на руже, а не как в параметрах 5 блоков. это я все пробовал. На один пример сталкнулся как обойти overflow:hidden. Если блок с overflow: hidden является статичным (position:static - все блоки статичны по умолчанию) то его потомки с position:absolute проигнорируют свойство overflow. Я пробовал то же что то не получилось, может где то пропускаю position:relative

Comment: А если внутри блока item делать контейнер с overflow: hidden, и прятать туда все содержимое, за исключением списка меню?

Comment: это как? я что то не понял.

Comment: Я тогда не совсем понимаю задачу целиком. Для чего нужно сохранить overflow: hidden на внешнем блоке-контейнере?